# How to alias a static class function in PHP

Tags: php, class, static, alias

In `PHP`, I have a class with a static method:

```
class Foo {
   public static function bar($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
        //logic here
   }
}
```

I want to create an alias of the static method called `star()` for backwards compatibility. It is called the same way:

```
 Foo::star('a', 'b', 'c');
```

What is the best way to do this? I'd prefer if I can change the number of parameters or order of `bar()` this change automatically propagates to `star()` as well.

Comment: `func_get_args()` + `call_user_func_array()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static function star()
{
    return call_user_func_array(array('Foo', 'bar'), func_get_args());
}
```

References:

- http://php.net/call_user_func_array
- http://php.net/func_get_args

Answer (score 1):

The short (and fun!) answer to your question is to store your function in a `trait` then alias the function when you import the trait.  This will ensure both functions have the same method signature.

```
// Tested on PHP 5.4.16
trait BarTrait
{
    public static function bar($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
        echo $arg1, $arg2, $arg3, "\n";
    }
}

class TestClass
{
    use BarTrait { bar as star; }
}
TestClass::bar(1, 2, 3);
TestClass::star(1, 2, 3);
```

The long answer is that I don't think there's any reason that you would ever need to change the function signature for the `star()` method.

If you are keeping the `star()` method, it is because you either have an API that you don't want to break, or you have too many call-sites to fix in the short-term.

In both cases, the only way to safely add more parameters to the `star()` method would be to use optional parameters, i.e. `star($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4 = null, $arg5 = null)`  This would mean that `bar()` would need to have optional parameters as well.

And if `bar()` has optional parms, then again there is no need to change the method signature of `star()`.

You simply let `star()` call-through to `bar()` with the non-optional parameters:

```
class Foo {
    public static function bar($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4 = null, $arg5 = null) {
        //logic here
    }
    public static function star($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
        return static::bar($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
    }
}
```

Any call to `star()` that you would modify to use the new parameters can just as easily be modified to call `far()` instead.

If you have a case where you really would need to change the signature of `star()` I would be interested in hearing more about it.

-D